# Why select max partitioned column is much slower than indexed one?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a big partitioned table (300+M rows, 70 active partitions). The table has clustered PK of (K0, K1) and it's partitioned on column K1. And K1 has very low selectivity.

However the following query takes a half minute and the scan count is 170 and logical read is 603K.

```
select max(K1) from table
```

However the similar query on on non-partitioned table with index on K1 takes no time and scan count is 1 and logical read is 5.

Should a none partitioned index be created on K1?

**Edit:**
Plan text for partitioned table without index on K1. With clustered PK on K0,K1, before create an index on C1.

```
  |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=MAX([partialagg1005])))
       |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
            |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([partialagg1005]=MAX([DB1].[dbo].[table1].[K1])))
                 |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DB1].[dbo].[table1].[PK_dbo_tabl1]))
```

Plan text for non-partitioned table with index on K1.

```
  |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=MAX([DB1].[dbo].[table2].[K1])))
       |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
            |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([Db1].[dbo].[table2].[idx_K1]), ORDERED BACKWARD)
```

Plan text for partitioned table with clustered PK on K0,K1, and index on C1.

```
  |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=MAX([partialagg1005])))
       |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
            |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([partialagg1005]=MAX([db1].[dbo].[table1].[K1])))
                 |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([db1].[dbo].[table1].[IX_C1]))
```

Comment: Are your indexes partition aligned?  What indexes exist now?

Comment: Also what datatype is `K1`?

Comment: Can you check post the execution plans for both cases? Wondering if one has generated a parallel plan.

Comment: @JNK The table has clustered index/PK (K0, K1). The data type of K1 is Date. There is another index on a non-key column.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith I've updated the question to include the execution plans.

Comment: Please provide the definition of the table, including the partitioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think I mis-understood/mis-read the question initially.

> The table is partitioned on column K1. However the following query
>   takes a half minute and the scan count is 170 and logical read is
>   603K.

To satisfy the MAX(k1) query in this case requires a clustered index scan of each of the 70 partitions.

> However the similar query on on non-partitioned table with index on K1
>   takes no time and scan count is 1 and logical read is 5.

With an index defined on K1, an ORDERED BACKWARD scan of the index is chosen, which probably translates to 4 pages read from the non-leaf index pages plus 1 for the leaf level.

Answer (score 2):

The order of your index keys is the issue.  You can create a partition aligned index on `K1` to resolve this pretty easily.

Right now your index on `K0, K1` can't be used directly to find the max value quickly since `K1` is the second key.

Comment: The table is huge and K1 has very low selectivity and it's partitioned. It seems SQL server engine should be able to figure out from the partition meta information?

Comment: @NickW it still needs to check the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is partitioned or not,

```
select max(K1) from table
```

needs `INDEX(k1)` or an index *starting* with `K1`.  And it must be an ordered index (such as BTree), not Hash.