# Why the query scan all the partitions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I have the following partitioned table

```
create table T (Month char(6), ID int, .... primary key (ID, Month)) on psMonth(Month)
```

The partition function is

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pfMonth](char(6)) AS 
RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (N'200001', .... N'200705', N'200706', N'200707', ....)
```

However, the *actual partition count* of following query shows is 260 instead of 1?

```
select count(*)
from T (nolock)
where Month = '200706'
```

The execution plan is

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[globalagg1006],0)))
       |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([globalagg1006]=SUM([partialagg1005])))
            |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
                 |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([partialagg1005]=Count(*)))
                      |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DB].[dbo].[T].[PK_T]), WHERE:([DB].[dbo].[T].[Month]=[@1]))
```

**Update:**
The query run fast and the *Actual Partition Count* is 1 if I run the following query.

```
select count(*), $partition.pfMonth(Month)
from T with (nolock)
where Month = '200706'
group by $partition.pfMonth(Month)
```

**Update 2:**
The following query also only scan one partition.

```
select count(*), min($partition.pfByMonth(Month))
from T 
where Month = '200707'
```

**Update 3:**
The original SQL scans only one partition now. No clue what happened. The only difference is that more data has been inserted into the table.
**Answer:** I used a CTE which wrapped the table. And it worked around the issue caused by type precedence. (However, the CTE didn't work around the issue at first though, the whole thing is strange and unpredictable.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your column is of type `CHAR(6)`. Your filter is of type `VARCHAR` (perhaps counter intuitive, but that what the constant literal `'200706'` is). The rules of [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) dictate that the comparison occurs using the type with higher precedence, ie. the VARCHAR type. This is a different type than the partitioning function, therefore you do not get partition elimination.

Try this instead:

```
select count(*)
from T (nolock)
where Month = CAST('200706' as CHAR(6));
```

Your plan should get a partitioning elimination filter.

Comment: It always scans only one partition now. I don't know what happened. Even if I change the where clause to `where Month = cast('200706' as varchar(6))`

Comment: You didn't change the definition of the table/PF, did you? Ie. it still has the same column type and clustered index key as in your original post.

Comment: The definition of the table/PF is not changed. One of my ssis package is still loading the data into this table. It's really strange that suddenly the query only use one partition now.

Comment: It scans all the partitions if I change where clause to `where Month = 200706`. Is it any setting force the constant string literal char instead of `varchar`?

Comment: In fact I found that it can be worked around by using CTE to wrap the partitioned table. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

This is directly related to [your other question.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/why-select-max-partitioned-column-is-much-slower-than-indexed-one)

You don't have an index on your partition key alone, it's the second key on your PK.  Because of this the engine needs to check every row.  If you had an index on that field then it could check just the index.

Comment: Why the second query (in the update section of my question) only scan one partition without a index?

Comment: Because you are directly invoking the partition you need.  The optimizer can't infer the partition you need without an index to point the way.

Comment: There is no condition filtering the result by partition ID though. In fact, I tried `select count(*), min($partition.pfMonth(Month))
from T where Month = '200708'` and it still only scan one partition.

Comment: By invoking `$partition` you are specifying the partition to search, albeit indirectly.  Without this guidance the engine needs to check all the partitions because, again, **you have no index on the field you are checking**

Comment: @NickW, JNK is right. The `$partition` tells the optimizer where to look. If you want elimination to happen automatically without specifying the partition function, SQL Server needs some other clue (e.g. a non-clustered index on the `Month` column).

Comment: Thanks. In fact, I just changed the clustered PK from (Month, ID) to (ID, Month) in order to eliminate the non-clustered index on ID. It seems I will still need an index on Month. Should I keep the cluster PK as (Month, ID)?

Comment: @NickW It depends on what your queries look like.  If  you ALWAYS include month but sometimes include ID, I would use `Month, ID`

Comment: I would think that makes more sense, since it would align with your partition function, but it might be counter-productive if you do a lot of queries using ID irrespective of date. It's hard to tell you what's best with limited information (e.g. is ID unique within a given month, a given day, or at all?).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes, the ID is unique whith a given month. The PK was (Month, ID).

Comment: The table has hundreds of millions of rows. And the partitioned column has only 70 distinct values. It seems not a good idea to create an index on such a low selectivity column?